# ARM OpenCL support for cl_khr_fp64 extension

Tags: arm, opencl, mali

I'm using OpenCL on Mali GPUs. [Official doc](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0538f/BJEEFIBD.html) states there is no support for *double* types.
Is there a workaround to use *double* ? Does ARM intends to support it in the next releases of its OpenCL implementation ?

Comment: A "workaround" would be to implement double precision in software, however that would be a lot of work and probably not have good performance. As for what ARM intends to do, you'd have to ask them :) Hopefully one of the devs sees your question.

Comment: You are probably interested in the double-single precision arithmetic functions defined in [http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/).  They are written in Fortran but should be easy enough to port to OpenCL C.  Unfortunately, just adding two numbers is already about 4 times as many operations vs. native single precision.  More complex operations are even slower!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM supports this extension in recent releases of the OpenCL Mali drivers. It is not yet publicly documented anywhere, but it is included in the binary drivers available at [malideveloper.arm.com](http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/features/mali-t6xx-gpu-user-space-drivers/).